# Reading web camera with MediaCapture on windows desktop

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8.1, ms-media-foundation, webcam-capture

I need to process frames from web camera on Windows 8.1 phones, tablets and desktop.
I already have implementation for phones and tablets (=store apps) that uses custom media foundation transform to access the frames. Now I’m working on a desktop version.

MSDN says [MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241124) class is supported on both store apps and desktop apps. The third-party [MediaCaptureWPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MMaitre.MediaCaptureWPF/) works OK in place of the missing CaptureElement.

However [MediaCapture.AddEffectAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211961) documentation says “*effectActivationID: The class identifier of the activatable runtime class that implements the effect.*”
And I [can’t use a custom WinRT component in a desktop app](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73a6b511-0181-4032-8f72-6bd1f24e45fd/calling-custom-c-winrt-component-from-c-console-app?forum=winappswithcsharp).

There's also another option to add an effect, MediaCapture.AddVideoEffectAsync, that takes the IVideoEffectDefinition argument instead of the class ID. However that interface is [only supported on the phones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.effects.ivideoeffectdefinition).

So, my question is.
Can I use MediaCapture class + custom MF transform on Windows 8 desktop platform? How?

Or do I need to developer an MF source reader just to support the desktop platform? Of there's better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to create a separate WPF app for desktop? Desktop also runs tablet/phone apps from the store.

Comment: To support windows 7.
To use APIs only available on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like MediaCapture isn't compatible with custom MFTs when running on desktop.

I ended up implementing media sink instead, based on the code [from this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776058/Capturing-Live-video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows-an).

Unfortunately, [the relevant parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697548(v=vs.85).aspx) of the media foundation framework are marked “[desktop apps only]”. It looks I will have to support 2 distinct versions of the frame grabber, one for the desktop, another one for the store + phone.